# Facebook API search for hashtag

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch all public Facebook posts containing a hashtag that is a combination of words glued together. For example "#ThisIsMyHashTag", using the [graph search api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/) however the posts are not being found. Searching when the hashtag is an actual word works fine.

Does anyone know of a way to get this to work?

EDIT: It appears that some hastags with multiple words are in there e.g. "#BreakingBadMarathon". Sorry for changing the question, does anyone know if this only works for really popular hashtags, or maybe it's that the search index takes a while to update?

EDIT 2: OK, so now some of the posts are showing up for my hashtag, but not all of them are. When making the call earlier, 2 recent posts appeared, but not older ones, then when running it again later, one of the earlier posts appeared. But some before the earliest, some in between the posts that are returned and some posts I made after the most recent one in the response are not returned. I wonder if the posts were stored in different data centres and some of them are getting indexed and some aren't? Anyone else got any ideas why some public posts are appearing and others aren't?

Comment: This has been asked a lot of times. Did you searched this ques before posting? Anyways, there's no API for hashtags as of now.

Comment: Yes, I have searched all over SO, the other answers only mention real words, not hashtag with compound words, so it's a different question.

Answer (score 16):

Note that as of August 2014 and Graph API 2.0, Facebook has deprecated the post search functionality:

[Using the Graph API (v1.0) > Available Search Types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v1.0#searchtypes):

> **post**: Search all public posts. Does not support limit/offset paging. This is not available in v2.0 or later versions of the API

Comment: Is there any replacement? Without, it makes this question and all answers pretty much useless!

Comment: Apparently, the only way to do it is to get access to the Public Feed API, which is impossible. So in other worlds there is no any replacement to it

Answer (score 7):

I resolved this question in that way:

It's possible query for hashtag using, '%23' instead of # (the corresponding URL encoding `# -> '%23'`) in query string.

Example : https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23myhashtag.

This method seems to be working fine.

Comment: macro is right, we can fetch all public #tag by using 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%23evanna&&limit=10000&access_token=YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN' and second way is we can get it from Facebook Stream table using FQL. But via we will not get all public #tag only for friends or user. Think twice when u going to caste down vote guys.

Comment: {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#11) Post search has been deprecated",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 11
   }
}

Answer (score 4):

Try this there is two way:

**`First Use Facebook Graph API:`**

> https://graph.facebook.com/ search?q=%23YOU-HASH-VALUE &limit=10000
>   &access_token=YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN

**`Second way is read Stream Table via FQL:`**

But it won't give you Public data. it only works with user or friends and to read the stream table you need '**`read_stream`**' permissions

> // FQL Query with Full user data

```
SELECT 

action_links, actor_id, app_data, app_id, attachment, 
attribution, call_to_action, claim_count, comment_info, 
created_time, description, description_tags, expiration_timestamp, 
feed_targeting, filter_key, impressions, is_exportable, 
is_hidden, is_popular, is_published, like_info, message, 
message_tags, parent_post_id, permalink, place, post_id, 
privacy, promotion_status, scheduled_publish_time, share_count, 
share_info, source_id, subscribed, tagged_ids, target_id, 
targeting, timeline_visibility, type, updated_time, via_id, 
viewer_id, with_location, with_tags, xid, likes

FROM stream 
WHERE (source_id=me()  ) AND strpos(lower(message),lower('#evanna')) >=0
```

Open '`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/`' and add '`search?q=%23hashtag-string`' use valid access_token and ta da :)

`More help see this attached Image`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Since posting the question I found out through an informed source that Facebook "doesn't guarantee that all public posts will be returned". This is the same as twitter, although in my experience, with twitter, about 95% of the public tweets were returned. Whereas from Facebook, it was more like 10%. Basically, if you are building something that requires you get most of the public posts from Facebook using a hashtag - don't.

Comment: @neilcrookes: Hi, Thank you so much for your valuable comment. I was not aware of these Facebook facts that they don't return 100% data. Yep, I am going to start on a project which requires maximum hash tag data from Facebook. Kindly help me if there is any other way to pull user's hash tag data from Facebook. Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: I know of not other way. Sorry. We have to wait until Facebook release a hashtag API, and even then we need to do some pretty thorough testing to confirm it returns all the data, not just some it. I'd put your project on hold for now if I were you.

Comment: @neilcrookes can you clarify your source on the no guarantee bit? I'm writing an app now and noticing similar results, but without some sort of documentation, however generic, I'm going to have a hard time explaining to stakeholders than it's a casualty of the API, not our code.

Comment: My source is an Engineer who now works at Facebook in San Fran, and who is a great friend and former colleague that I worked with for 5 years. I approached him when I was noticing issues in my app, and as a favour he checked in with his colleagues in the platform team at Facebook who gave the no-guarantee answer. Good luck convincing the stakeholders.

Comment: Search via `search?q=%23hashtag`  or other query string is now unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

'/v1.0/search' has been deprecated in 2.0 Version and your application can't use v1.0 API, if it was created after 30th April 2014