# Facebook Public Feed Api search for Hashtags?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-public-feed-api

I have a few Questions. 
Since Facebooks `Graph API v2.0` you only get access to the Facebook `Public Feed API` if you request to gain a access from Facebook. And they only provide it to a few Media Companys.

**So my first Question:**

Is it posibly that i gain access if i request it?

**My second Question:**

I only want to search for all public posts with a specified Hashtag in it. For example i want to find all public posts with the Hashtag `"#sports"` in a specified `timespan of 1 Year`. Can i handle that with the normal `Graph API` of Facebook or do i have to do it through the `Public Feed API`?

**And my last Question:**

Are there any Providers who can provide me a service like that? So if i cant get access to the facebook public feed api, I can get the posts to another provider whitch has the premission to do it? Are there any Companies who can provide that? Pricing doesnt matter.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Question:

> Access to the Public Feed API is restricted to a limited set of media publishers and usage requires prior approval by Facebook. **You cannot apply to use the API at this time.**

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed

---

Second Question:

There is no post search anymore, see this thread: [Facebook API search for hashtag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034754/facebook-api-search-for-hashtag)

---

Third Question:

See this list: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mediasolutions/partners